# How can I change the font in the XPages source code editor?

Tags: xpages

How can I change the font type, color and size for the XPages source code editor?

What about highlighting tags, etc?

thanks,

Howard

Answer (score 8):

For the font size... 
Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->Basics->Text Font

For syntax coloring: 
Preferences->XML->XML Files->Editor->Syntax Coloring